# Nested grids result in rows automatically filling the largest size

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid that works great:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">Lots and lots and lots of text...</div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, I have the page divided into 4, with all divs the same size. As the text gets longer in the first card, it expands, pushing the other cards down (making them **smaller**) before ultimately pushing them off the page, increasing the height of the div.

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/641b47d9bbc7a13880a53b0da04bd3bb

If I wrap this another div

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 1fr;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="controls">
    <h1>Text here.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the `.grid` rows all match each others height. Which is cool, but not what I want in this scenario. How can I make them behave similarly to the previous example?

Incorrect behaviour:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/5637d435b48628aa5f31d5b996bbc6bf

Comment: `20vh 1fr` -- > `20vh minmax(0,1fr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1fr` in `grid-template-rows: 20vh 1fr;` makes the second grid take up the rest of the available space after your controls `div`. That space then gets equally divided in four quarters by the CSS settings of your second grid:

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Simply remove the `grid-template-rows` style from your second grid so the grid row height is set to auto.

```
.wrap{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 1fr;
}
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.card{
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```